# MovableType: Displaying CustomField Images Instead of Links

Tags: regex, movabletype

The default behavior of the image custom field is to display a link to the image. Eg.:

```
<span class="mt-enclosure mt-enclosure-image" style="display: inline;"><a href="/images/judd_jon.jpg">judd_jon-1.jpg</a></span>
```

Is there a way to output just the location or the name of the image so I could display just the image? Eg.:

```
<img src="/images/judd_jon.jpg" alt="" />
```

Comment: How is this regex related?

Comment: The image link could be extracted via regex, but I can’t get it to work. There was a solution for a previous version, but it doesn’t work anymore: `<MTCustomFieldValue regex_replace="/span class=.mt-enclosure mt-enclosure-image.+?href(.+?)View image<\/a><\/span>/","img src$1">`

Comment: It's not  good practice to use regex to parse html in any shape or form. I'm not saying its impossible, but if you have to ask for help to do it, it's not the solution for you.

Comment: It’s not the best solution, but it used to work with an older version of MovableType. Since they changed something in the output it stopped working and I’m not versed enough to adapt the regular expression…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simon, the rule here is that the asset context starts from the custom field tag, which in your case is "mt:heroic_image" to which you would add "Asset", like on:

Adding "Asset" to the tag as in the line above gives it asset context so that you could use any of the movable type assets tags from:

http://www.movabletype.org/documentation/appendices/tags/template-tag-types.html#assets

Answer (score 3):

You can use MT tags to output the path to the image:

```
<mt:CustomFieldNameAsset><mt:AssetURL><mt:AssetThumbnail width="200"></mt:CustomFieldNameAsset>
```

CustomFieldName is the "template tag" from the edit custom field screen.

mt:AssetURL = outputs the URL of the asset on the filesystem
mt:AssetThumbnailURL = outputs a generated thumbnail of the image

There are a [number of great tags](http://www.movabletype.org/documentation/appendices/tags/template-tag-types.html#assets) you can use.

Comment: This should have worked, since the custom field is for image assets. Unfortunately, MT reports an error: “tag outside of the context of an asset.”

Comment: Simon: please share the exact template code that returns this error, and the configuration of the custom field.

Comment: The custom field’s name is `<mt:heroic_image>` and its type is an image. So I’m using the following code in MT:
`<MT:hero_imageAsset>
<$MTAssetThumbnailLink width="200"$>
</MT:hero_imageAsset>`
The error message from MT is: _<MT:hero_imageAsset> at line 66 is unrecognized._

Comment: @SimonZirkunow compare "heroic" vs "hero" -- suspect that's where your trouble is.

Comment: Thanks, that worked! That was embarrassing missing that typo.